# How I can programatically create another Column in resx file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resourcedictionary, resx

**Description:**
I am working on a Dictionary for a **MultiLingual**,**MultiOrganization** **CMS**.

Currently we are using Database solution (Sql Server), but due to massive database traffic we are looking for an alternative solution and I have found .resx files.

Here we will be creating .resx file programatically and one .resx file/Language.
On every .resx file we want to add an organizationId.You can see the .resx file for English Language below.

We want this structure in .resx

```
Name    Value        Comment                   OrganizationId
About   About     this file is for english          1
Login   Login     this file is for english          2
```

The scenario is that when in my cms a lang is added i will be creating a resource file with it which will contain the dictionary(English key , that language value) for the language.

Now everything would have gone as planned if **one word would have one meaning** but there is a requirement that `Two organization can one have different meaning` for a single word.

for example word `hello` will have meaning `abc` for organization1 and it will have meaning `abc2` for organization2.

**My Question:**
1.How can I do this using .resx file and if its not possible using .resx file then what is the most efficient (speed,maintainance,flexibility) alternate for this scenario.

**My Code:**
Currently I am trying [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542(v=vs.110).aspx) sample:

```
             // Define a resource file named CarResources.resx. 
            using (ResXResourceWriter resx = new ResXResourceWriter(@"D:\VSProjects\CreateResourceFile\CreateResourceFile\CarResources.resx"))
            {

                resx.AddResource(new ResXDataNode("About", "About"){    Comment = "this file is for english" });
                resx.AddResource("Login", "Login");
                resx.AddResource("News", "News");
                resx.AddResource("Headline", "Headline");
                resx.AddResource("Information", SystemIcons.Information);

            }
```

Comment: The organization Id value does not belong in a resource file.

Comment: @tdbeckett yes , this organizationId is the main problem, how can I add this OrganizationId column into .resx file

Answer (score 4):

Resx files have strict schema and it does not include additional field you want. So even if you manage to add the filed (i.e. with regular XML API) standard .Net resource methods will likely fail to process such modified files.

Depending on your needs you may either use completely custom XML (LINQ-to-XML provides an easy way to create/read XML documents) or if you really want to use resx files - partition files by organization (in addition to language) like

```
text.org1.en-us.resx
text.org2.en-us.resx
text.org1.fr.rest
```

Comment: Thnks for your quick and effective answer.Btw there are more than 150 organizations/WebSites are currently running on our CMS, so i think partitioning file will not be a good idea because I guess creating and maintaining large number of dynamic resouce file is an headache.As for now  i am quite impressed by the linq to xml idea.

Comment: @Sadaquat Side note:  answer assumes you've already looked at more traditional solutions to DB traffic like in-memory caching (using .Net classes) or even distributed caching (memcached, redis,...). Switching to disk based files would not be my first choice...

Comment: What you say about creating my own resouce reader/writer. Which will require more effort 1.creating a custom resource reader/writer for .resx files  or 2.Creating an xml file from start to end?